# Evaluating a symbolic summation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eval

Following code throws out an error.

```
syms z positive;
syms n;
syms m;
N = 10;
Ms = 10;
Es = 1;
pd = 0.9;
pd_dash = 1-pd;
pf = 0.1;
pf_dash = 1-pf;
pr = 0.1;
qr = 1-pr;
p = 0.005
pi = pf_dash*p;
pb = pd_dash*p;
qi = 1-pi;
qb = 1-pb;

sm = symsum( z^((n+1)*Es), n, 0, N-1 );
temp_sum = symsum(z^((n+m+1)*Es)*qr^(n+m)*pr, m, 0, N-1);

z=1; %assume a value of z
x = eval(sm); %works fine
y = eval(temp_sum);
% Error:The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

Please suggest a way to resolve this.

The problem that I suspect is: the temp_sum comes out to be in piecewise(...) which eval is not capable of evaluating.

Comment: Please edit your question to show all of your code including how all variables are defined/allocated. Your example is not runnable and thus does not demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Hi Horchler, I have made the required editing. The example is now runnable.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually did:

1. Create a symbolic expression
2. Create a variable `z` which is unused
3. Call a undocumented function `sym/eval`

I assume you wanted to:

1. Create a symbolic expression
2. Substitute z with 1: `temp_sum=subs(temp_sum,z,1)`
3. get the result. Here I don't know what you really have because I don't know which variables are symbolic unknowns and which constants. Try `simplify(temp_sum)`. If you substituted all unknowns it should return a number.

Comment: What do mean that `sym/eval` is undocumented: `help sym/eval`? It's not a lot of documentation, I admit. It's basically just a  front-end for [`sym/evalin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/evalin.html). Did you forget that  class name is `sym`, not `syms`, perhaps?

Comment: To my opinion a undocumented function is not part of the documentation (http://www.mathworks.com/help/index.html). syms sym was a typo, fixed it.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the reply, but the problem is that the simplifying doesn't return a number. It returns another symbol which has only numbers. For example simplify(temp_sum) return a symbol whose value is number1/number2. It doesn't perform the final division.

Comment: The computation is finished, a fraction is one of the base classes when using symbolic math, because it's important to store numbers like 1/3 without precision loss. Use `double(temp_sum)` to convert.